# history.pushState() not working properly on phone

Tags: javascript, pushstate

I have a chap app where user first fills up a form then they are redirected to the chat page. Now the problem is when user clicks the back button they goes back to the login form.

So I used this code to prevent going back,

```js
history.pushState({}, '', "inbox");

history.pushState({}, '', "again-inbox");

window.onpopstate = ()=>{
  history.forward();
}
```

It works fine on PC but does not work on android browsers.

Comment: Not sure about `socket.io`,  but pure WebSockets certainly don't..  Have you maybe got something else attached to the `beforeunload` event,.  Maybe something in `socket.io` is using this event.  Also maybe unrelated you normally do `return e.returnValue = 'message'`

Comment: Umm.. I'm not sure why the connection is dropping. That's the main problem.

Comment: Have you checked if any other events are attached to `beforeunload` or maybe `unload` event.  For example in Chrome you can click on the Body tag in the debugger, and then go to Event Listeners, and see if there is any others attached.  It might be one of these that's closing your socket..